# Not Getting Output on Creating UITextView Programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

### AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

}
```

### ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func loadView()
{
    self.view = UIViewUsingTextField()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

### UIViewUsingTextField.swift

```
import UIKit

class UIViewUsingTextField: UIView
{

var blueview: UIView?

 init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.setupView()

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

  func setupView()
   {
    self.blueview = UIView()
    self.blueview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.blueview?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(self.blueview!)

    let centerXconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let centerYconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    self.addConstraint(centerXconstraint)
    self.addConstraint(centerYconstraint)

   let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

   let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueview!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

    self.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
    self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    self.addConstraints([centerXconstraint,centerYconstraint,widthConstraint,heightConstraint])
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

}
```

By using above code I am not abel to get the UITextView of Blue color in my simulator. I want to create UITextview Programmatically, I can not find the actual issue that why I am not getting the Blue UITextView as output of this code. I am getting only white Screen in my simulator as output of this code. I have tried to code as per [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfKv1MYxnA4) link. Will anybody please help me to fix this issue to have a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the custom class to the `View`:

[image: View class]

**Below code will add an `blueView` of 200x200 at the center of the View:**

```
import UIKit

class UIViewUsingTextField: UIView
{

    var blueView : UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        setupView()

    }

    func setupView() {
        self.blueView = UIView()
        self.blueView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.blueView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(self.blueView!)

        let blueViewCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let blueViewCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let blueViewWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

        let blueViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

        self.addConstraints([blueViewCenterXConstraint,blueViewCenterYConstraint,blueViewWidthConstraint,blueViewHeightConstraint])
    }
}
```

**If you want your blueView to cover whole View:**

```
func setupView() {
    self.blueView = UIView()
    self.blueView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.blueView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(self.blueView!)


    let constLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!,
                                          attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
                                          relatedBy: .Equal,
                                          toItem: self,
                                          attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(constLeading)

    let constTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
                                           relatedBy: .Equal,
                                           toItem: self,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(constTrailing)

    let constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!,
                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
                                      relatedBy: .Equal,
                                      toItem: self,
                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin,
                                      multiplier: 1,
                                      constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(constTop)

    let consBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.blueView!,
                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
                                        relatedBy: .Equal,
                                        toItem: self,
                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin,
                                        multiplier: 1,
                                        constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(consBottom)
}
```

Comment: yes i want to apply constraint for Universal App. How can i set the Custom class to the View ?

Comment: I could get the blue box but without applied constraints. I want to correct the constraint if they are not correct.

Comment: I was trying to add constraints as per this video :  "   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfKv1MYxnA4   "  How can i correct the mistake to have the autolayout constraints.

Comment: I am really much obliged to you for such your precious efforts. I am trying to add one more UIView that is red. i need to place both beside each other for every device horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a frame to your view and disabling the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints will makes it working for you.

```
self.blueview?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
 // self.blueview?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: will this work for the universal app having the functionality of autolayout ?